# Permission Denied: running rosjava pubsub tutorial

Tags: rosmake, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the rosjava_tutorial_pubsub tutorial, but every time I try to "rosmake" it, I get the following error about not being able to create "ros.properties." I'm honestly not sure what to do from here, and I've looked through the rest of the answer base. Thanks in advance!

```
kevinaboos@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace$ roscd rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/
kevinaboos@ubuntu:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['rosjava_tutorial_pubsub']                                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rosjava_tutorial_pubsub']                                                                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/kevinaboos/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111115-023614                                                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rosjava_tutorial_pubsub'] to:
['rosjava_tutorial_pubsub']                                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.  This may take a few seconds.                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_ros [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package test_ros                                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosjava_bootstrap [ make ]                                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosjava_bootstrap ROS_NOBUILD in package rosjava_bootstrap                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> apache_commons_util [ make ]                                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< apache_commons_util ROS_NOBUILD in package apache_commons_util                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> apache_xmlrpc [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< apache_xmlrpc ROS_NOBUILD in package apache_xmlrpc                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosjava [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosjava ROS_NOBUILD in package rosjava                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosjava_tutorial_pubsub [ make ]                                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] All 3 linesrosjava_tutorial_pubsub: 0.0 sec ]                                                                                                                           [ 1 Active 27/28 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  rosrun rosjava_bootstrap generate_properties.py rosjava_tutorial_pubsub > ros.properties
  /bin/sh: cannot create ros.properties: Permission denied
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosjava_tutorial_pubsub written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/kevinaboos/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111115-023614/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/build_output.log              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosjava_tutorial_pubsub [FAIL] [ 0.07 seconds ]                                                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosjava_tutorial_pubsub. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Built 28 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] /home/kevinaboos/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111115-023614
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11940/permission-denied:-running-rosjava-pubsub-tutorial/) by [kevinaboos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1385/kevinaboos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) on 2011-11-15**:
You installed the tutorial in /opt/ros which require root permission to access. You could probably copy the folder to somewhere in your home directory and then add the directory into ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Alternatively, you could run rosmake as root.  PS. the rosjava package may miss a ROS_NOBUILD file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Copying from the comment:

You installed the tutorial in /opt/ros which require root permission to access. You could probably copy the folder to somewhere in your home directory and then add the directory into ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Alternatively, you could run rosmake as root. PS. the rosjava package may miss a ROS_NOBUILD file.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0